# what is 'mutation_root' in Apollo-graphql mutations? I'm getting the error that says a field not found in "mutation_root"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm following their official tutorial and the query tutorial works perfectly but the mutation throws the error in the title when I press the button in the following code. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/

```
const ADD_USER = gql`
  mutation AddUser($name: String!) {
    addUser(name: $name) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

```
const [addUser, {data}] = useMutation(ADD_USER);
```

```
<Button
  title="press"
  onPress={() => addUser({variables: {name: 'Avneesh'}})}
/>
```